# How to upload DAG file into AWS-MWAA-LOCAL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mwaa

I am using docker on windows and following this guide (https://github.com/aws/aws-mwaa-local-runner) I was able to install the mwaa-local, but I was not able to upload a dag to UI.

I just put my DAG file on aws-mwaa-local-runner\dags folder and runned it ./mwaa-local-env build-image
but I cannot see any dag in UI.

Does anyone knows the step-by-step to upload a DAG into aws-mwaa-local?

Comment: Are there any DAG parsing errors? Do you see any errors in the terminal where Airflow is run? Did you start Airflow: `./mwaa-local-env start`?

Comment: Yes, I have started airflow with this command. /mwaa-local-env start I can see the UI but nothing appear there. I cannot see any errors when I run it.

Comment: Can you share the DAG file?

Comment: Hi @Andrew Nguonly I can share my DAG but for now I just want to confirm that this is the right way to upload a DAG file into UI aws-mwaa-local? Just put the file in aws-mwaa-local-runner\dags and then run ./mwaa-local-env build   is that right?  if yes, the file tutorial.py should appear in UI right?
As I told, nothing is showing in my UI and I don't know what is happeng

Comment: Yes, you just need to run the `build` and `start` commands and the default `tutorial` DAG should appear in Airflow UI.

Comment: I did all this steps, but I do not understand why any DAG appears on UI. I can't see any error when building